# Encadenar promesas en TypeScript - Angular 2

Tags: angularjs-2.0, http, typescript, promesas

Tengo una aplicación que consume una API REST. Con un GET obtengo un JSON y dentro de ese JSON hay varias URL con las que también hago GET. Por el propósito de la aplicación tengo que tener cuidado con la sincronización (de ahí que use promesas) ¿Cómo puedo pasar las URL del primer JSON a la segunda promesa para acceder a ellas ahí?

```
this.http.get(data.jobs[i].url + this.finalURL).subscribe(
    response => {
    let data2 = response.json();
    let numberOfFails: number = 0;
    var init;
    if (data2.builds.length < 10){
       init = data2.builds.length-1;
    } else {
       init = 9;
    }
    for (var j = init; j >= 0; j--){
       console.log("Iteracion " + j + " numberOfFails " + numberOfFails);
       this.http.get(data2.builds[j].url + this.finalURL).subscribe(response => {
       let data3 = response.json();
       console.log(data3);
       if(data3.result == "FAILURE"){
          numberOfFails = numberOfFails+1;
       }
       }, error => console.error(error));
    }
```

Y lo dicho, hace falta cierta sincronización porque es posible que continue sin que se resuelvan todas las peticiones GET haciendo que, por ejemplo, numberOfFails pueda variar.

Comment: bienvenido a SOes, ¿Te parece si editas tu pregunta agregando el código que has hecho por favor? Saludos :D

Comment: Revisa este post, ahi esta la solución, aunque es algo compleja. http://academia-binaria.com/comunicaciones-http-observables-con-angular2/

Comment: Puedes utilizar el .then despues de la promise. El codigo dentro del .then se ejecuta al llegar la peticion echa, aprovecha i lanza peticiones des de aquí.

Comment: Como puedo hacer eso? Me puedes poner un ejemplo, por favor

Comment: No son Promesas, son observables. En este caso puede ser de utilidad `Observable#forkJoin`

Answer (score 1):

La llamada a `this.http.get(...)` no devuelve una promesa, sino [un Observable, que es un concepto distinto](https://www.intelygenz.es/introduccion-a-reactive-programming-con-rxjs-por-gustavo-marin/).

Entre las operaciones que podemos realizar con observables está `map`, que permite crear un nuevo observable con la transformación de los resultados del primero:

Por tanto la solución a lo que quieres podría ser la siguiente:

```
let urlStream = this.http.get(data.jobs[i].url + this.finalURL)
  .map((res: Response) => {
    let data2 = response.json();
    let numberOfFails: number = 0;
    var init;
    if (data2.builds.length < 10){
       init = data2.builds.length-1;
    } else {
       init = 9;
    }
    let urls=[];
    for (var j = init; j >= 0; j--){
      urls.push(data2.builds[j].url + this.finalURL);
    }
    return Observable.from(urls); //convierte el array en un stream
  });

  urlStream.observe((url) =>{
     //el parámetro url es cada uno de las URL generadas arriba,
     //esta función se podrá ejecutar hasta 10 veces, porque hemos 
     //generado un máximo de 10 URLs
  }
```